# Which strategy for Hibernate Inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, annotations

My webapp domain consists of three entities:

- **Person**, which represent a human subject, with all personal data, such as name, surname, telephone number and so on.
- **Customer** and **Supplier** : child of 'Person'. Each of them have got specific properties.

Now I want to use Hibernate (with *annotations*) for mapping my model to a rdbms schema with **customers** and **suppliers** tables. I do not want a generic Person table, I don't need it.

I want a customers table with name,surname,... + specific customer fields AND a suppliers table with name,surname.... + specific supplier fields.

Do you think it's stupid? What's the better solution instead? And **how to implement it**?

Comment: How about reading the documentation? See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e7287 and http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-unionsubclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not stupid and it is directly supported in Hibernate, see: [9.1.5. Table per concrete class](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete).

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id" type="long" column="PERSON_ID">
        <generator class="sequence"/>
    </id>
    ...
    <union-subclass name="Customer" table="CUSTOMER">
        ...
    </union-subclass>
    <union-subclass name="Supplier" table="SUPPLIER">
        ...
    </union-subclass>
</class>
```

In JPA with annotations you can write:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Person {
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Customer extends Person {
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Supplier extends Person {
  ...
}
```

If you don't need to perform cross-inheritance queries like: "*give me all people with name "Smith", no matter whether they are customers or suppliers*", this strategy is pretty good.

Comment: 1) does that create a PERSON table?

Comment: @FabioB.: no it doesn't, as you requested.